# Codeigniter cannot call core class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to call my core controller class in `application/core` from my child controller in `application/controllers`. I have `Home` controller `home.php` in `application/controllers` that extends `Public_Controller` in `application/core`. My `home.php` is like this:

```
<?php
class Home extends Public_Controller
{
    public $data = array(
        'page' => 'home',
        'main_view' => 'home'
    );

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
    }
}
```

in the core folder, I have public_controller.php

```
<?php
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    // Layout untuk "Publik"
    public $layout = 'layout';
}
```

From the code above, MY_Controller also located in core. here's the code

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Autoload model.
        $model = strtolower(get_class($this));
        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'models/' . $model . '_model.php')) {
            $this->load->model($model . '_model', $model);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in summary i have controllers `home` in `application/controllers` that extends `public_controller` in `application/core` and the `public_controller` extends `my_controller` that also in `application/core`.
I already modified config/config.php by adding this code

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

so I can connect base controllers to controllers by reference from this https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2010/02/08/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY/

But it's still not working. Saying that

> Fatal error: Class 'Public_Controller' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cipsb\application\controllers\home.php on line 2

Is there anything I can do for solving this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i didn't pay attention to Codeigniter version i'm using. I use codeigniter 3.1.0 and the reference I use is for older codeigniter version. For codeigniter 3 just use this in config/config.php

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php')) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```